# Android PanoramaGL doesn't support image

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that has panorama viewer and I'm using PanoramaGL. All my images are downloaded from the internet, and size of every images are 1200x1200. I tried to resize the image, but it was unhelpfull. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in order to resize it:

```
PLSpherical2Panorama panorama = new PLSpherical2Panorama();

    int heigh_pxl= output.getHeight();
    int width_pxl= output.getWidth();

    double size=Utils.sizeOf(output)/1048576;
    Log.d(TAG, "prima: "+size +" MB     "+width_pxl+"x"+heigh_pxl);

    if(width_pxl>=2048){
        width_pxl=2048;
        heigh_pxl=1024;
        output=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 2048, 1024, false);
        size=Utils.sizeOf(output)/1048576;
        Log.d(TAG, "dopo: "+size+" MB"+2048+"x"+1024);
    }else{
        width_pxl=Utils.nearestPOwerOf2(width_pxl);
        output=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, width_pxl, width_pxl/2, false);
    }
```